How can you make 3d renderings of optical systems with tikz?
I am trying to make an optical system using tikz. The goal is to resemble Fig 1a. of this link (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.06014). I also tried to follow figures like this (Fig 1a in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.06626 and in here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.06732).
Here is what I got:
I started with code I found in this site:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-0.8,-0.2) -- (0.8,-0.2) -- (1.2,-0.6) -- (1.2,-1.8) -- (-1.2,-1.8) -- (-1.2,-0.6)--(-0.8,-0.2);
\draw  (-1.8,0.8) rectangle (1.8,0.4);
\draw (-1.2,1.4) -- (-1.6,2) -- (-1.8,3) -- (-1.8,3.8) -- (1.8,3.8) -- (1.8,3) -- (1.6,2) -- (1.2,1.4)--(-1.2,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And tried to adapted to this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

% Define colors
\colorlet{beamred}{red!70!white}
\colorlet{beamgreen}{green!70!white}
\colorlet{objectivebody}{gray!40}
\colorlet{samplecolor}{blue!30}

% Define focal length and beam start position
\def\f{4} % Focal length
\def\beamstart{6} % Starting position of beams
\def\d{0.4} % Height of the sample

% Upper Objective (cylindrical)
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,\beamstart)}]
    % Cylinder body
    \fill[objectivebody] (-2,0) rectangle (2,-2);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (-2,-2);
    \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2,-2);
    % Bottom face (detailed)
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2)}]
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 0.5);
        \fill[gray!20] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 0.5);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (1.8 and 0.45);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.5 and 0.125);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}

% Lower Objective (cylindrical)
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-\beamstart)}]
    % Cylinder body
    \fill[objectivebody] (-2,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (-2,2);
    \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2,2);
    % Top face (detailed)
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,2)}]
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 0.5);
        \fill[gray!20] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 0.5);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (1.8 and 0.45);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.5 and 0.125);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}

% Sample rectangle
%\fill[samplecolor] (-1.5,-\d/2) rectangle (1.5,\d/2);
%\draw[thick] (-1.5,-\d/2) rectangle (1.5,\d/2);

% Green beam (coming into the top of upper objective)
\fill[beamgreen,opacity=0.2] (-2,\beamstart+2) rectangle (2,\beamstart);
\draw[thick,beamgreen] (-2,\beamstart+2) -- (-2,\beamstart);
\draw[thick,beamgreen] (2,\beamstart+2) -- (2,\beamstart);

% Green beam (coming into the top of upper objective)
\fill[beamgreen,opacity=0.3] (-2,\beamstart+2) rectangle (2,\beamstart);
% Red beam (coming into the bottom of lower objective)
\fill[beamred,opacity=0.3] (-2,-\beamstart-2) rectangle (2,-\beamstart);

% Green beam from bottom face of upper objective
\fill[beamgreen,opacity=0.3] (-2,\beamstart-2) .. controls (-1.3,\beamstart-3) and (-0.7,1) .. (-0.3,0)
                             -- (0.3,0) .. controls (0.7,1) and (1.3,\beamstart-3) .. (2,\beamstart-2) -- cycle;

% Red beam from top face of lower objective
\fill[beamred,opacity=0.3] (-2,-\beamstart+2) .. controls (-1.3,-\beamstart+3) and (-0.7,-1) .. (-0.3,0)
                           -- (0.3,0) .. controls (0.7,-1) and (1.3,-\beamstart+3) .. (2,-\beamstart+2) -- cycle;

% Focal point
\fill[cyan] (0,0) circle (0.1);
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (0.1);

% Labels
\iffalse
\node at (3,\beamstart-1) {Upper Objective};
\node at (3,-\beamstart+1) {Lower Objective};
\node[beamgreen] at (3,\beamstart+1) {Green beam};
\node[beamred] at (3,-\beamstart-1) {Red beam};
\node at (2,0.3) {z = 0 (Focal point)};
\node at (2,-0.7) {Sample};

% Focal length labels
\draw[<->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,\beamstart-2) node[midway,right] {f};
\draw[<->] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,-\beamstart+2) node[midway,right] {f};

% Z-axis
\draw[->,thick] (-4,-\beamstart-3) -- (-4,\beamstart+3) node[above] {z};
% X-axis
\draw[->,thick] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {x};
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Which leads to this:

How do you make 3d renderings using tikz. I have tried so far but this is the best I could get. Is there a way to make the beams look more 3d. Is it possible to modify the perspective such as to make the objectives also more 3d, more realistic? Is it possible to use pst-optexp such that the objective behaves like a lens so it would focus in a more realistic way? Any help would be much appreciated it

tikz is not capable of drawing the arrows, light cones and sphere in Fig 1. (a) in perspective. It can do a pretty darn good job in highlighting the important features nonetheless, but these images were not made with tikz. Asymptote has features which do this more easily. If you want to use tikz, the solution does become more complicated, as it is a 2d software which can only fake 3d.
